# My emacs24 doesn't have scroll bar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

My emacs24 doesn't have a scroll bar...

how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Just turn on the scroll bar mode:

```
(scroll-bar-mode t)
```

You can add this line to your `.emacs`.

Answer (score 1):

Try eval this:

```
(set-scroll-bar-mode t)
```

or you can put it in your `.emacs`.